# Regex of JDBC Connection String

Tags: regex, jdbc

I want to capture the **server** (host and port) part of the JDBC connection string. A JDBC connection string starts with **jdbc:**, database type and then the server information. Note that, after the database type name the string can have `@` such as `oracle:thin:@` or can have `//` such as `db2://`. Examples are given below:

```
jdbc:oracle:@mydbhost:1521/mydbservice
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcp://mydbhost:1521/mydbservice
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcp://mydbhost1,mydbhost2:1521/mydbservice
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcp://mydbhost1:5521,mydbhost2:1521/mydbservice
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcp://mydbhost1:5521/mydbservice:dedicated
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://mydbhost1:5521/mydbservice?wallet_location=/work/wallet
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://mydbhost1:5521/mydbservice?wallet_location=/work/wallet&ssl_server_cert_dn="Server DN"
"jdbc:db2://sysmvs1.stl.ibm.com:5021/STLEC1"
```

In the above examples,  `mydbhost:1521` and `sysmvs1.stl.ibm.com:5021` are the server for oracle and db2 databases. I have written below regex and it could not capture the first oracle server.

```
(?<dbms>(?:jdbc:[^\/]*))(\/\/)?(?<server>[^\/\?\s`'";]+)
```

[image]

Note that, I want to capture until I find `@` or go beyond @ if `//` is present. Since, I am capturing until I find `/`, I could could not capture the first server properly. Now, How can I greedily check if we have `//` after `@` if `@` is found and then take the later part? I have my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Csxo1w/1).

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/Lq9W8f/1. I replaced your optional `(\/\/)?` with a mandatory `//` or a `@` without being followed by a `//`: `(\/\/|@(?!.*\/\/))` judging by your description

Comment: The JDBC specification **only** specifies a JDBC URL to be `jdbc:<subprotocol>:<subname>`, where `<subname>` is entirely driver-specific. You're assuming too much structure, which will not necessarily be valid for all JDBC drivers (some drivers don't even have hostnames in their URL).